# How to add a link_to in a select_tag with Rails/ERB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, helper, link-to

I have the following code in my **index.html.erb**

```
 <%= select_tag 'team_id', options_for_select(@teams.map{|team| ["#{team.name} #
  {team.nick}", team.id] }) %>
```

Where would I add a link_to helper within that block? Can I even add a link_to for select_tag?

The desired link_to would go to '/Teamleader/ID_OF_OPTION_PICKED'

**UPDATE:**

To be more clear; when a user selects an option from the select tag, I want to redirect the page to the desired link (from link_to).

Comment: when you select an option from the select tag, you want to redirect the page to your desired link, is it?

Comment: yes @shweta, I'll update my question with this info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<%= select_tag 'team_id', options_from_collection_for_select(@teams, "id", "name") %>

<script>
    $(function(){
      $('#team_id').bind('change', function () {
         var url = "/Teamleader/" + $(this).val()
          if (url) {
              window.location.replace(url);
          }
          return false;
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Evgeniy, seems like I can't add a link_to in a select_tag. Jquery it is!

Comment: This was my solution but I made a change.

window.location.href = url;

If you use replace, the back button will not work correctly, but if you set the href to the url it will ;)

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
<%= select_tag 'team_id', options_from_collection_for_select(@teams, "id", "name"),:onchange => "window.location.replace('/Teamleader/'+this.value);" %>
```