# Rails create a dropdown of links

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app with a table called `workorders`.  Each workorder can have children (other workorders).

On the workorder show page, I'm trying to create a dropdown to link to that workorder's children.

I'm getting the drop-down and the list of children.

But, the children aren't LINKS.  Selecting one doesn't do anything. The Rails log doesn't show anything.  And the code in the html page is not a link.

This is the code:

```
<select>
 <option>Children</option>
 <% Workorder.find(@workorder).children.each do |workorder| %>
    <option>
         <%= link_to workorder.id_desc, edit_workorder_path(workorder) %>
    </option>
 <% end %>
</select>
```

PS - should I be using a `select_tag` instead?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a hyperlink inside an option tag. You could use the id of the row (probably is value of the row) and just do a simple JS redirect to the desired page.

See a JS example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14453234/217187