# Rails 4 select_tag with nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, nested-resources, html-select

I have a resource that looks like this:

```
resources :teams do
  [...]
  get 'tags/:tag', to: "teams#show", as: :tag
end
```

Each `Team` can have multiple `Posts` which in it's turn can have multiple `Tags`. In my teams show view I want to display a `select_tag` that lists all the tags for the `Team`'s `Posts`. When the user selects a tag I want to redirect them and list all posts for that tag. I have go it to work, but not with my nested resource and the `URLs` that I want. My implementation currently looks like this (I use `HAML`):

```
/ View
= form_tag team_path(@team), method: 'get', class: 'tag_form' do
  .input-group
    = select_tag "tag", options_from_collection_for_select(@team_tags, 'id', 'name', params[:tag]), prompt: "All tags", class: 'chosen-select'

# Controller

def show

  @team_tags = @team.posts.tag_counts_on(:tags)

  if params[:tag] && !params[:tag].blank?
    tag = Tag.find(params[:tag])
    @posts = @team.posts.tagged_with(tag.name)
  else
    @posts = @team.posts
  end

end
```

This works, but gives me an url that looks like this:

```
teams/1?utf8=✓&tag=1
```

What I want is:

```
teams/1/tags/tag-name
```

Is that possible to do, and how would that look?

Comment: this is a problem of routing: [read this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: Thanks, I think the routes is correct. In one other place I use `link_to` to redirect users to `teams/1/tags/tag-name`, which works.  But I'm not sure how to do it with my `select_tag`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14454137/2128691), you might be able to get this to work:

```
= select_tag "tag", 
  options_from_collection_for_select(@team_tags, 
  'id', 
  'name', 
  params[:tag]), 
  {prompt: "All tags", 
  class: 'chosen-select'}, 
  {onchange: "window.location.replace('/teams/' + @team.id + '/tags/' + this.value);"}
```

the only thing i'm not sure about is if `@team.id` will interpolated correctly inside `:onchange`, so you could also try changing the `onchange` line to this:

```
onchange: "window.location.replace('/teams/#{@team.id}/tags/' + this.value);"
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. As by @rneves answer I used name as value instead of id.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use, or something like this (with your fields) on the controller

```
tag = Tag.where("id = ? OR name = ?", params[:tag], params[:tag])
```

And on the select you should use the name as value, maybe with a gsub like this

```
tag.name.gsub(" ", "-")
```